# Virtualization, Graphics Processor and Optane Memory

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, virtualization, vsphere, optane

I visited local stores for purchasing a new laptop. I am not a gamer. I have to purchase a laptop with good configuration so that I can run 4-5 virtual machines and may be in coming time I can do practise for vSphere.

That’s why, I planned for a laptop with i5 8th Gen, 4GB Graphics and 16GB RAM but because of Optane memory concept, I got confused. I read some articles for Optane memory.

At the end, I am still confused,

How Optane memory concept is helpful for my requirement and

On the behalf of Optane memory should I compromise with Graphics processor and RAM?

Pls guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Smith

Comment: You should think of Optane as an SSD cache drive.  A GPU isn't really required for vSphere to function.  How much system memory you will need entirely depends on how much memory you assign to each of your 5 VMs.  You will likely find the system specifications you indicated are not powerful enough to run 5 VMs.

Comment: Initially I have to run 4-5 VMs using VMware Workstations. Later on I’ll go for vSphere. As you said, A GPU isn't really required for vSphere to function. Does it mean, it doesn’t matter what GPU (2GB or 4GB) is in laptop?

Comment: And you said, You will likely find the system specifications you indicated are not powerful enough to run 5 VMs. Do you mean, i5 8th Gen with 2GB GPU and 16 GB RAM is not more efficient for running 4-5 VMs?

Comment: "Do you mean, i5 8th Gen with 2GB GPU and 16 GB RAM is not more efficient for running 4-5 VMs?" - I know absolutely nothing about the VMs you plan to run.  The amount of VMs you expect to run on a sub-optimal mobile processor is not realistic.

Comment: Okay. Let me know, how do I know, how many VMs are recommended to run on mobile processor (i5-8th Gen)?

Comment: What will your VMs do, what OSes?  vSphere isn't something you'd install on a laptop, it's going to have compatibility issues and you're not going to be able to use it directly, you remote into a vSphere server, it's not console based.  Skip optane and up your RAM to 32GB and go with an NVME SSD. VMs performance bottlenecks with disk IO, then RAM, and finally CPU, except in rare/special cases.

Comment: @user249711 - Your question is too broad and cannot be answered in it's current form

Comment: I try to simplify it.

Comment: Initially I have to run 3-4 virtual machines (Windows 10 & Windows Server 2016) on VMware Workstation. I planned for a laptop with i5 8th Gen (i5-8250U), 4GB AMD Graphics and 16GB RAM but because of Optane memory concept, I got confused.
i5-8250U supports Optane Memory, Speed Shift Technology, Hyper-Threading Technology, Virtualization Technology (VT-x), Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) and VT-x with Extended Page Tables.
However, at the end, I got confused because of correlation of Optane Memory with Graphics Processor for virtualization process.